# in kotlin app, message listview not displaying emoji view

Tags: android, kotlin, view, emoji, logcat

[image]i have got emoji view in logcat of android studio. but not getting that emoji view in app. i have set emoji textview in layout but its not visible in listview. blank screen only getting

```
    val p = message.parseAsHtml()                            
                        var h = message.parseAsHtml()                       


                        mxd.message =  "$h"
```

logcat :
D/pro: if(message.startsWith message.parseAsHtml()----

"if(message.startsWith "$h"----"----

```
     <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    emojicon:emojiSize="@dimen/emoji_size_default"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chatDp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
    android:maxWidth="250dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/incoming_msg"
    android:fontFamily="@font/manrope_medium"
    tools:text="h"
    />
```

in  message list adapter, getting emoji in logcat code:

```
      private fun configureViewHolder2(vh2: ViewHolder2, position: Int) {
    Log.d("msglistadapter", "configureViewHolder2")
    vh2.label1.text = values[position].getMessage()

    val text: String? = values[position].getMessage()
    Log.d("msglistadapter", "configureViewHolder2 values[position].getMessage()" +values[position].getMessage().toString())
```

logcat output:

D/msglistadapter: configureViewHolder2 values[position].getMessage()

Answer (score 0):

yesterday, i got emoji view in listview when i have changed the size of emoji in the  layout file of emoji textview. [I have attached the screenshot of image for your reference.